# Add query string to all pages after user logged in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to add query string to all pages including homepage.after user logged in. as example after user logged in homepage url need to look like domain.com?aff=1234567 and other links also modify with custom query string such as page domain.com?p=1&aff=1234567

anyone has idea how to do this or how can i use wp_redirect for this

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your theme functions.php

```
function query_arg_for_logged_user($permalink){
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return add_query_arg('preview', wp_generate_password(8), $permalink);
    }
}

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
add_filter( 'home_url', 'query_arg_for_logged_user', 11, 1);
add_filter( 'post_link', 'query_arg_for_logged_user', 10, 1);
add_filter( 'page_link', 'query_arg_for_logged_user', 10, 1);
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'query_arg_for_logged_user', 10, 1);
add_filter( 'category_link', 'query_arg_for_logged_user', 11, 1);
add_filter( 'tag_link', 'query_arg_for_logged_user', 10, 1);
add_filter( 'author_link', 'query_arg_for_logged_user', 11, 1);
add_filter( 'day_link', 'query_arg_for_logged_user', 11, 1);
add_filter( 'month_link', 'query_arg_for_logged_user', 11, 1);
add_filter( 'year_link', 'query_arg_for_logged_user', 11, 1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

add following code to functions.php,

```
add_action('wp_head', 'your_function');
function your_function(){
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $genre_url = add_query_arg('aff', '1234567', get_permalink());
    } 
}
```

Hope this will help you.
for more information,

- [is_user_logged_in()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/)
- [How can I include a query string with get_permalink](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/257682/how-can-i-include-a-query-string-with-get-permalink)
- [wp_head action hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head)
- [get_permalink()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/)